# Dont understand this implementaion of equals method

Tags: java, oop, methods, equals

Few days ago my professor showed us how to implement equals method and many more.

This is code example from his equals method and i dont understand one part:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj)
        return true;
    if (obj == null)
        return false;
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
        return false;
    Knjiga other = (Knjiga) obj;
    return Objects.equals(isbn,other.isbn);
}
```

In first if statement he check if this (current object) has the same reference with object obj ( that's what == operator does ? compare only two references)

And if they got the same reference it will return true ?
But we will never check other fields, such as isbn and many more we could put because method will never come to the part if these two objects have the same reference.

In my point of view this method is similar to double equals operator cuz either of these two wont check fields, only reference ?

Comment: If the two references are the same then it's one object, not two.

Comment: Your professor doesn't use braces on his if statements? Wow. Also: Objects.equals already checks the references and null values.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the two objects being compared have the same reference, this is the same object, and there's no point in comparing anything else. You can return `true` immediately and save some comparisons.

The other properties are guaranteed to be equal in this case.

Comment: Hmm, but if i am write equals we make to check if all the fields are the same ? And this will only check reference ?

Comment: @MiljanRakita it checks just the reference only if the references are equal. Otherwise, it proceeds with the rest of the checks.

Comment: So if the references are equal this method will return true ?
It is the same as we only used  someOb == otherOb instead of using this equals method someOb.equals(otherOb) Because they both now check only references ?

Comment: If only all the fields are the same, it is not the same object (better: instance). You can have two cars with the same brand, color, motor, wheels etc, but still the instances are different. If you, for example, make a copy of the car papers and you give the copy to someone else, both copies refer to the exact same instance

Comment: @MiljanRakita A simple way to explain this is similar to what devnull69 said. You can have the same car as your friend. They can be purchased at the same time from the same dealership with the same color, model, year, etc, but they each have a unique Vehicle Identification Number. This VID is similar to what a program will identify an Object with. The == operator returns true if and only if those objects have the same ID (IE, they are the exact same object).

Answer (score 1):

If  `(this == obj)` is true, it's the same object so it's obviously equal.

If these two if clauses aren't true

```
if (obj == null)
    return false;
if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
    return false;
```

it means that the two objects are both from the same class but not the same object so then with

```
Knjiga other = (Knjiga) obj;
return Objects.equals(isbn,other.isbn);
```

is checked if the `isbn` of the two objects are equal, if so the two `Knjiga` objects are the same too.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
    String s1 = new String("Test");
    String s2 = new String("Test");
    String s3 = s2;
    String s4 = "Test";
    String s5 = "Test";
    System.out.println(s1 == s2); //Prints false
    System.out.println(s2 == s3); //Prints true
    System.out.println(s3 == s4); //Prints false
    System.out.println(s4 == s5); //Prints true
```

`s1` and `s2` are new instances of a String object. Just because they have the same apparent value "Test", they do not necessarily have the same value to your program. As a result, these two are not equal in terms of their objects.

`s3` is an exact copy of `s2`, meaning it is an exact duplicate of the String instance of `s2`. This in turn means that they are Objectively equal in terms of their instance.

`s4` is a String directly assigned to "Test" and is not necessarily a new instance of a String object. Therefore, objectively, they are not equal. (See [String Interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning))

`s5` is also directly assigned to "Test", therefore it is equivalent to `s4`. Again, see string interning for the details on why this works.

This is a less complicated way of describing your situation, but should give a good explanation on the basics of Object comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Logic of `equals` method of your code:

1. `First condition:` It is obvious. If reference of both objects are same, return true

   ```
   if (this == obj)
       return true;
   ```
2. `Second condition:` If other object is NULL, return false

   ```
   if (obj == null)
      return false;
   ```
3. `Third condition:`Now both current object and other objects are not null. Check if className is same for both objects. If class is different, return false.

   ```
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
       return false;
   ```
4. `Fourth condition:` Now both objects are not null and belong to same class. Check whether attribute(s) [`isbn` in this example] of these objects are same or not. If they are not same, return false.

   ```
    Knjiga other = (Knjiga) obj;
    return Objects.equals(isbn,other.isbn);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Objects reference are compared using ==. Usually when you override the equals method in your class to compare two objects of your class, it is good to use the reference equal first. This will save from comparing all the attributes inside the object.
Consider the example Cat class

```
public class Cat {
 String country;
 int numberOfCats;
 public Cat(String country, int numberOfCats) {
    this.country = country;
    this.numberOfCats = numberOfCats;
 }
 public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if(obj == null)
        return false;
    Cat eqlObj = (Cat) obj;
    if(this.country.equals(eqlObj.country) && this.numberOfCats == eqlObj.numberOfCats)
        return true;    
    return false;
 }
}
```

Test class

```
public class TestCat {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Cat obj1 = new Cat("France", 9600);
    Cat obj2 = obj1;
    obj1.equals(obj2);
 }
}
```

[image]

In the above test class both obj1 and obj2 point to the same Cat object. Comparing the reference will return "true", i.e first if block in equals.

Another Test

```
public class TestCat {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
    Cat obj1 = new Cat("France", 9600);
    Cat obj2 = new Cat("France", 9600);
    obj1.equals(obj2);
 }
}
```

[image]

In this test class new object is created for obj1 and obj2 so the reference they hold will be different. Value assigned in the object are same. First if block in the equals will fail as reference are different. Third if block in the equals will compare the values and return "true".

Hope this helps..

Comment: Thanks, it helps a lot !